# How can i add checkbox in listbox(asp.net)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can i add Checkbox in listbox. i want to make it in asp.net .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use [CheckBoxList](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_checkboxlist.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above, but the specific answer to your question (as far as I am aware) is that you can't.  You can only add items which inherit from ListItem.  Definitley look to CheckBoxList.